# Какой вариант будет правильнее?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно будет ***"Я не считаю место, в котором родился, родным"*** или ***"Я не считаю место в котором родился, родным"***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Я не считаю место, в котором родился, родным"***

Запятая нужна, поскольку "в котором родился" требует обособления. Это подчиненное предложение (с опущенным подлежащим).
И обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на то, что пробелы ставятся после запятых, а не перед ними.